# Unity shader : can you fix this shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

[image]

I want to get rid strange colored regions in the outline of the tree. Here's my shader's code for tree sprite:

```
    Shader "Unlit/Transparent Color Z on 2" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
}

SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
    LOD 100

    ZWrite On Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha Cull Off
    //ZTest Always
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 

    Pass {

        Lighting Off
        SetTexture [_MainTex] {

            constantColor [_Color]

            Combine texture * constant, texture * constant 

         } 
    }
}
}
```

Additionally, a tree's sorting order is 7 and background brick's sorting order is 14. and tree's z position is -11, and brick's z positions is a -8.8.

Answer (score 0):

You commented out "**ZTest Always**" so the fallback "**ZTest LEqual**" is used instead. The outline you see is the mesh (with the "Tight" option in the Sprite properties) being written to the Z-buffer, preventing the brick from being drawn properly.